# I need load this code before load another code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am consuming the REST API of WooCommerce, through a web application developed with Reactjs. But I need to extract the data from the api before the web is loaded (Since the products are shown on the web and if I do not have the products, the loop that runs through the array that should contain the products extracted from the REST API

```
  WooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result) {
    let a = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
    a.forEach((element, index) => {
      console.log(element.name + " | " + element.regular_price);
    });
    info = a;
    return a;
  });

info.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log(element);
    resultado.push(<Producto index = {index} pasarCarrito = {func} 
    image={element.images[0].src} title={element.name } prize= 
    {element.regular_price} description={element.description} />)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your API calls in the lifecycle method :

> componentDidMount()

example :

```
export default class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {person: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.UserList();
  }

  UserList() {
    $.getJSON('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(({ results }) => this.setState({ person: results }));
  }

  render() {
    const persons = this.state.person.map((item, i) => (
      <div>
        <h1>{ item.name.first }</h1>
        <span>{ item.cell }, { item.email }</span>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
        <div className="panel-list">{ persons }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Or write a hook to do it , https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/  (might as well be at the bleeding edge right ?)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help, but componentDidMount() never load my code :(

Comment: are you using class based component?

Comment: class SeccionPc extends React.Component{

Comment: I can see, when i dont use WooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result)  the method didMont load the code but i need this code

Answer (score 0):

A common technique in React is to get the data in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and then put the data in state when the request has finished, and use this piece of state in the render method of the component.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then(function(result) {
      const products = result.toJSON().body;
      this.setState({ products });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((element, id) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {element.name} | {element.regular_price}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```